# How to upload APKs to Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

This option, which was present last week, seems to be missing altogether from Google Play Console now. I need to upload an APK and roll it out to production. When creating a new release, I now only have the option to "add from library", with seemingly no option to upload anything to said library.

Changing to App Bundles is not an option, as this is a cordova app, and cordova can only output APKs and does not support exporting app bundles.

Is there a way to upload APKs at all?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: I think the issue was caused by a CORS plugin for Chrome, it's working now.